# Shell - what is this script doing?

Tags: bash, shell, apache-camel

In my code someone has written following camel route. The input to `feed.in` is a csv file. I can't get my head around what is the shell script doing.

```
    <route id="route-id-1">
        <from uri="{{feed.in}}" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelExecCommandArgs">
            <simple>-h \\|AAAAA\\||\\|BBBBB\\||\\|CCCCC\\||\\|DDDD\\||.ssif\\| ${in.header.CamelFileAbsolutePath} ${in.header.CamelFileAbsolutePath}.filtered</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="ref:execGrep"/>
    </route>

<endpoint id="execGrep" uri="exec:${APP_SCRIPTS}/camel-egrep.sh"/>
```

content of `camel-egrep.sh` is :

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep ${@:1:$(($#-1))} > ${@: -1}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is: what is that shell script doing when those arguments are passed.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should [edit] the question to show how `camel-egrep.sh` is actually called, i.e., what arguments are passed to it -- and what the output is.

Comment: Have you tried to run it with different inputs and see what it yields?

Comment: `$@` : This contains list of all the arguments.
 `$#` : Number of arguments. 
 `${@:1}` : From 1st argument. 
 `${@:1:5}` : From 1st arg to 5th arg
 `$(($#-1)) `: Total arguments - 1 arg. 
 `${@:1:$(($#-1))}` : From first argument to the second last argument.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `{{feed.in}}` evaluates to the name of a directory. The Camel route will become active when a file is placed in the directory. It will read the file, and execute the `camel-egrep` script with particular arguments. The second-to-last arguments are the filename, and the filename with ".filtered" appended.

I would guess that the overall result will be to create a file `xxx.filtered` for each file `xxx` that is presented, where the generated file consists of lines in the original file which match the search pattern `AAAAA|...`.